# How to save data from broken GPT, GUID and unmountable, no type volumes?

Tags: partition, filevault, mount, efi, guid

I have a Macbook Pro mid 2012 and 750GB hard drive. I tried to delete Windows partition on the hard disk and now I can't access my main Mac partition (disk index 2) anymore. It shows something like "FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF" and I don't even know what it is.

I don't want to format/delete this partition because it has important files. The main Mac partition had FileVault enabled and this is the output from sudo gpt -r show disk0

```
 start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640  1167843728      2  GPT part - FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF
  1168253368        1608         
  1168254976   126689280      3  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1294944256      262144         
  1295206400   168673192      4  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1463879592     1269536      5  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1465149128           7         
  1465149135          32         Sec GPT table
  1465149167           1         Sec GPT header
```

I appreciate any help or suggestions!

Comment: How exactly did you delete this partition? What do you mean "I can't access my main Mac partition"? Are you trying to boot into OS X or trying to mount the disk from another system? What do `diskutil list` and `diskutil cs list`  show?

Comment: The history of the disk (or partition table) seems to be incomplete. You write: you had a filevault enabled partition and a Windows partition. Now we see an unknown partition (disk0s2) and an non-encrypted CoreStorage partition (disk0s4). The partition table doesn't show much free space (300 MiB) so you either reclaimed the ex-Windows partition to add/install another OS X partition or disk0s2 was the Windows partition (which would be a **very** uncommon set-up).

Answer (score 1):

I deleted from the MAC-Disk utility window. No, I am not trying to boot into OS X or trying to mount the disk from another system. I am just trying to save my files from that partition.

Here are the screens:

**diskutil list**

[image: **diskutil list**]
**diskutil cs list**

[image: diskutil cs list]
Thanks!

Comment: The history of the disk (or partition table) seems to be incomplete. You wrote in your question (if you are the same memyana): you had a filevault enabled partition and a Windows partition. Now we see an unknown partition (disk0s2) and an non-encrypted CoreStorage partition (disk0s4). The partition table doesn't show much free space (300 MiB) so you either reclaimed the ex-Windows partition to add/install another OS X partition or disk0s2 was the Windows partition (which would be a **very** uncommon set-up). Please don't use multiple memyana accounts - that's confusing! Ask a mod to join them!